# How to fill a bezier and line based polygon?

Tags: lua, bezier

I have been working on a graphics library for some time now and have gotten to the point where I have to draw Bezier and line based fonts. Up to this point I am stuck with this:

[image: i]

[image: a]

The green lines are the Bezier paths, and the white part is what gets rendered.

The code I use for Beziers is [here](http://pastebin.com/s8qDC4NH). The one for lines is [here](http://pastebin.com/bKv55tch). For those who don't know that is Lua.

Path rendering (lines) : 32 - 39
  The algorithm is as follows:

1. Iterating from 0 to 1 at certain intervals
2. calculating the x and y with this formula: `(1-index)^2*x1+2*(1-index)*index*x2+index^2*x3`

Up to this point everything works fine. The green lines are generated using the path method.

The white part is rendered in a completely different way:

1. I get the x coordinates of the Beziers and lines at a particular Y, the put them into a table.
2. I iterate through the table and each time I encounter a point I change the value of state. In the same for loop is also check whether state is on. If it is, I draw a pixel to the screen.

To find the x values of a y, I use the getX method (line 46 in Bezier and line 31 in Line).

The code I use for the drawing itself is this one:

```
local xBuffer = {}
local state = false

for i=0,500 do
    for k,v in pairs(beziers) do
        a,b = v.getX(i)
        if a then
            xBuffer[round(a)] = 1
            if b then
                xBuffer[round(a)] = 1
            end
        end
    end
    for k,v in pairs(lines) do
        a = v.getX(i)
        if a then
            xBuffer[round(a)] = 1
        end
    end
    state = false
    for x=0,600 do
        if xBuffer[x] then
            state = not state
        end
        if state then
            love.graphics.points(x,i)
        end
    end
end
```

Quick explanation: for i,v in pairs iterates through the table given as an argument to pairs. love.graphics.points(x,y) sets a point at x,y.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly does one "get the X values at a particular Y" for a Bezier curve? I ask, because as an operation "for any curve", this is mathematically impossible: it's a parametric curve, and can have more than one X value for any one Y value (and vice versa). Just fill an outline that uses lines and Bezier curves by filling the polyline formed by taking the lines and inner hull edges for the Bezier curves, and add the fill that remains for each Bezier curve.

Comment: Some optimizations to make your code cleaner: 1) You redefine local variables at function beginning. Function arguments are already function-local, so they do just nothing. 2) For min-max operations, there're standard functions **math.min** and **math.max**. 3) You do already nice not to use slow table functions for insertion, but it's good practice to store the table size as field **n** for further use, because requesting the size isn't constant cost.

Comment: Explaining 2D rendering would be too much here, but i wrote a Lua library which includes rendering of shapes in form "m 0 0 l 10 0 b 10 5 0 5 0 0" in past. Maybe you get ideas of [the shape part](https://github.com/Youka/Yutils/blob/T1/src/Yutils.lua).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I actually found part of the issue. I didn't reset xBuffer after each of iteration.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/how-should-i-fill-a-shape-consisting-of-bezier-cures-and-straight-lines.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the help, but I figured it out in the end.

Comment: @Creator, please add your solution as an answer for future reference.

Comment: OK, I will post the code an explain it.